# How to make a div fly to another div after appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements that I want to move around to other divs when they are clicked. I found `appendTo`, but I don't know how to let the element fly to the other div in transition.

```
<div id="top">
  <button id="b1">B1</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="bottom">
  <button id="b2">B2</button>
</div>

<script>
$('#b1').click(function() {
  $('#b1').appendTo($('#bottom'));
})

$('#b2').click(function() {
  $('#b2').appendTo($('#top'));
})
</script>
```

Is there a simple way to make the buttons 'fly' after they are clicked? For now, I just make them fade out and into the new div.

Comment: 1. Create a "flying clone" as position:fixed at current coordinates. 2. append the element as visibility:hidden 3. fly the clone from current position to the element's new position using CSS `transition-timing`. 4. destroy the clone 5. Set visibility:visible to the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. create an element's "flying **clone**" as `position:fixed` at current coordinates.
2. **append the element** to destination
3. make the **element hidden** using `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0`
4. **animate the clone** from start coordinates to the element's new coordinates
5. **destroy the clone**
6. make the **element visible**
7. prevent fly if element is already in destination (i.e: on subsequent calls)

```js
/** 
 * Fly element to destination parent
 * Use like: flyMeTo("#bird", "#destinationParent")
 * @param el {String} Selector (or `this`) of the flying element
 * @param destination {String} Destination parent selector
 * @param prepend {Boolean} Optional. Set to true to use prepend (instead of append)
 */
function flyMeTo(elem, destination, prepend) {

  var $elem = $(elem);
  var $dest = $(destination);
  
  // Early exit - if already in destination
  if($elem.parent().is(destination)) return;
  
  var $klon = $elem.clone().insertAfter($elem);
  var start = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  $klon.css({position:"fixed", zIndex:9999, left:start.left, top:start.top, pointerEvents:'none'});
  $elem.css({opacity:0})[prepend?'prependTo':'appendTo']( $dest );

  var end = elem.getBoundingClientRect(); // Get new coordinates after append/prepend
  $klon.animate({left:end.left, top:end.top}, 600, function() {
    $klon.remove();         // Remove flying clone once it reaches destination
    $elem.css({opacity:1}); // Show original Element
  });
}


// DEMO:
$('#b1').click(function() {
  flyMeTo( this, '#bottom', true ); // By passing `true` it will prepend!
});
$('#b2').click(function() {
  flyMeTo( this, '#top' );
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="top">
  <button id="b1">B1</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="bottom">
  <button id="b2">B2</button>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to make a simpler version from your answer

Comment: @JunDalisay I'm glad you tried to simplify and understand the above code, but in the process (judging by your answer below) you actually broke it. If you need clarifications on the above code please leave a comment pointing to the specific parts.

Answer (score -1):

I stripped down Roko's answer to see which methods do what.

```
function flyMeTo( orig, destination ) {
  var $copy = $(orig).clone().insertAfter($(orig)); // duplicate the original button element

  $copy.css({position:"fixed"}); // dunno what this is for
  $(orig).css({opacity:0}).appendTo(destination); // make the orig invisible then append it to the other div still invisible

  var end = orig.getBoundingClientRect(); // now that the orig is at the new location, get its position
  $copy.animate({left:end.left, top:end.top}); // animate the duplicate to make it go to that position  
}
```

Comment: By stripping the accepted answer's code you made some crucial mistakes. 1. you're not setting the initial positions for the flying element. 2. after appending the $orig element, you never rest it's opacity to `1`. 3. You never destroy the flying clone element. 4. you're using the clone instead of the appended element. - So, to recap, the flying clone is for animation/visual purpose only. I'd suggest you to delete this answer (since adds nothing new or better), and if you need code-explanation, clarifications, leave a comment in the *comment* section of the provided answer.

Comment: I just needed to move the elements to other divs and the stripped version still works: http://jsfiddle.net/cybxj0aw/1/

Comment: It works from your point of view. If you inspect the source, after you click all your 3 images you'll end up having actually 6 images in the DOM! Another issue: click your images and try to scroll BODY: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/cybxj0aw/4/

Comment: Another issue your code has is that if you have events bound to your flying elements, once they incorrectly fly, the events are all lost http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/cybxj0aw/9/. If you use instead the suggested answer's code - all is much better: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/cybxj0aw/10/